# I cannot allocate a nsmutablearray as a class variable

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, allocation, init

I was having problem allocating the NSMutableArray in the player class, there is no warning in the compile time when I tried this way in the (id)init method: playerInventory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; But when I run the program, it gives me an error (EXC_BAD_ACCESS). I have checked over and over, but found nothing help. I am new to objective c and I don't have much knowledge in memory management in this language. But seemed that I cannot find the answer after my best effort.

the .h file

```
  @interface Player : NSObject
    {
        int playerLevel;
        int playerExp;
        NSMutableArray *playerInventory;
        NSString *playerName;
        BOOL isLastPlayerExist;
        NSData *xmlData;
        GDataXMLDocument *_xmlDoc;
    }
    @property (assign,readwrite) int playerLevel;
    @property (retain,readonly) NSString *playerName;
    @property (assign,readonly) BOOL isLastPlayerExist;
    @property (retain,readwrite) NSMutableArray *playerInventory;

    +(Player *)currentPlayer;
    -(void)loadXMLFile;
    -(void)loadRecentPlayer;
    -(void)loadPlayerStats;
    -(void)loadPlayerInventory;
    -(void)releaseXMLFile;


    @end
```

the .m file , deleted irrelevant implementations.

```
@implementation Player
static Player *sharedInstance = nil;

@synthesize playerLevel;
@synthesize playerName;
@synthesize isLastPlayerExist;
@synthesize playerInventory;

-(id) init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil){
        playerInventory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self loadXMLFile];
        [self loadRecentPlayer];
        [self loadPlayerStats];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) loadXMLFile{
    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath: NO];
    xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSError *error;
    _xmlDoc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData
                                   options:0 error:&error];
}

-(void) loadRecentPlayer{
    NSArray *playerInfo = [_xmlDoc.rootElement elementsForName:@"Player"];
    GDataXMLElement *currentName = (GDataXMLElement *)[playerInfo objectAtIndex:0];
    playerName = currentName.stringValue;
    NSLog(@"%@",playerName);
}

-(void) loadPlayerStats{
    NSString *xPath;
    NSArray *playerInfo;

    xPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"//Users/Player[Name = \"%@\"]/Level",playerName];
    playerInfo = [_xmlDoc.rootElement nodesForXPath:xPath error: nil];
    GDataXMLElement *level = (GDataXMLElement *)[playerInfo objectAtIndex:0];
    playerLevel = level.stringValue.intValue;

    xPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"//Users/Player[Name = \"%@\"]/Experience",playerName];
    playerInfo = [_xmlDoc.rootElement nodesForXPath:xPath error: nil];
    GDataXMLElement *exp = (GDataXMLElement *)[playerInfo objectAtIndex:0];
    playerExp = exp.stringValue.intValue;

    xPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"//Users/Player[Name = \"%@\"]/Inventory/CardID",playerName];
    playerInfo = [_xmlDoc.rootElement nodesForXPath:xPath error: nil];
    for(id obj in playerInfo){
        GDataXMLElement *card = (GDataXMLElement *)obj;
        [playerInventory  addObject: card.stringValue.intValue];
        NSLog(@"%d",card.stringValue.intValue);
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",playerInventory);

}


+(Player *)currentPlayer{
    if (sharedInstance == nil){
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (NSString *)dataFilePath:(BOOL)forSave {
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"userData" ofType:@"xml"];
}


@end
```

Comment: change

@synthesize playerInventory = _ playerInventory;

and allocate like following

_playerInventory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: wow, amazing. Thank you for your quick help. But where I can find these knowledge about the under scroll thing? That is the second time the under scroll messing me up this day.

Comment: FYI, that is not a class variable, but an instance variable. Objective-C does not have real class variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
@synthesize playerInventory = _ playerInventory;
```

and allocate like following

```
_playerInventory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```